# Sync Desktop with Dropbox - Symlink

Tags: macos, terminal, dropbox, symlink

I tend to work almost entirely off of my desktop, and I'm attempting to simplify my workflow. I want to sync my Desktop between my Work iMac and my Mac Mini at home.

I've sucessfully synced my Home computer's Desktop TO a Dropbox folder (So in Dropbox I have a /Dropbox/Desktop/ directory)

Now, what I want is to have the contents of this Dropbox directory on my Work computer's Desktop.

I've succeeded at making a symlink on my Work computer to the Dropbox folder, BUT, it simply appears like a shortcut. In other words, my work desktop has a icon that links to my Dropbox. I want my Work desktop to BE the (dropbox/desktop) folder.

Comment: See http://www.imore.com/how-sync-your-documents-desktop-and-any-other-folder-dropbox